# changing a button with a checkbox on another form. c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to change a buttons visible status with a checkbox that is on another form for example;

when the checkbox checked state changes on form 2 than the visible property for button 1 on form1 changes. If someone could point me in the right direction i would appropriate it thank you.

Comment: Please post your code and what you exactly tried so far.

Comment: well I have tried
form1 frm1 = new form1();
//then i called the object 
frm1.button1.visible = checkedbox1.checked;

Comment: When you do `form1 frm1 = new form1();` you create new instance of `form1` class, which is completely not related to your `form1` instance. It has its own button. It just not visible, because you didn't show this new form. Use events to notify form1 about something happened in form2

Answer (score 0):

Define event on `Form2`. E.g.

```
public event EventHandler StateChanged;
```

Raise this event when checkbox checked state changes:

```
private void Checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (StateChanged != null)
      StateChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Subscribe to this event in `Form1`

```
form2.StateChanged += Form2_StateChanged;
```

Change a button in this event handler:

```
private void Form2_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button.Visible = !button.Visible;
}
```

Comment: I usually try  button.Visible =false , does  button.Visible = !button.Visible, work??

Comment: @apomene `button.Visible = !button.Visible` changes visible state to opposite. If button is visible, then it hides button. If button is hidden, it shows button. You can do any logic in this event handler. That's just a sample

Answer (score 0):

Normally when I do something like this I add a method that calls it.

```
        Form1 with the button
public void SetVisibility(bool visible)
{
   Button.Visible = visible;
}

      Form 2 With CheckBox
CheckBox_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1.SetVisibility(CheckBox.Checked);
}
```

Adding a public method on your form also enables you to control it from others forms. Not sure what the best answer is, thats up to you.

EDIT:

Not related to the question but...

On Form 2

```
var form1Control = new Form1();
form1Control.SetVisibility(true);
```

Comment: @CodeGuy4Life I dont understand what you mean

Comment: i added the public void to form 1 and then on form 2 tried to type 
Form1.SetVisibility(CheckBox.Checked); and it would not recognize SetVisibility as an option...

Comment: I think it sounds like you trying to perform it on the Class object, not the implementation of it.

Comment: the problem here is the SetVisibility is not static. Either make it static or have a global instance of Form1

Comment: all i want is when i click the checkbox depending on the .checked bool it disables/hides button 1 ( the button and the checkbox are on different forms)